# Loop through variables to determine which is the largest

Tags: java, eclipse, instance-variables

So, for this example I have a method that needs to consider all the countries and continents entered and their associated populations. For background, this will be entered in the form (countryName, continent, population) etc in a txt document, so I have no idea what/how many continents are going to be used. In other methods these entries are split into the variables countryName, countryContinent, and countryPopulation.

This method needs to loop through all the entries, figure out how many continents are used, and then calculate the total populations of the continents (remember, five different countries from the same continent might be entered)

I've got the method to calculate the total populations of the continents entered and store these in a seperate list for each continent. From here, how do I compare the values of the lists to find out which continent has the highest population?

```
public String findMostPopulousContinent(){
    int asiaList = 0;
    int africaList = 0;
    int northAList = 0;
    int southAList = 0;
    int antList = 0;
    int euroList = 0;
    int austList = 0;
    int highestPop = 0;

    for (int n > 0, n < countryContinent.length; n++;)
        if (countryName[n].equals("Asia")){
            asiaList = asiaList + countryPopulation[n];
        }
        if (countryName[n].equals("Africa")){
            africaList = africaList + countryPopulation[n];
        }
        if (countryName[n].equals("North America")){
            northAList = northAList + countryPopulation[n];
        }
        if (countryName[n].equals("South America")){
            southAList = southAList + countryPopulation[n];
        }
        if (countryName[n].equals("Antarctica")){
            antList = antList + countryPopulation[n];
        }
        if (countryName[n].equals("Europe")){
            euroList = euroList + countryPopulation[n];
        }
        if (countryName[n].equals("Australia")){
            austList = austList + countryPopulation[n];
        }

        highestpop = Math.max(asiaList, africaList, northAList, southAList, antList, euroLost, austList);

}
```

And then from here, take the highest pop value and reassociate it with it's continent? highestpop should give me an int with the highest population but is there a way to know which list is highest and then return essentially "[Continent] has the highest population at [highest population]"

Part of the issue is that I don't know how many continents and countries will be used. I might only need three continents, I might need all seven.

Comment: Please post [minimally reproducible code excerpt](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Move you `max` calculation into the `if` statements

```
if (countryName[n].equals("Asia")){
        asiaList = asiaList + countryPopulation[n];
        if (asiaList > highestpop) {
            highestpop = asiaList;
            biggestContinent = "Asia";
        }
}
```

Of course this could be refactored to something like

```
 int storedBiggest (int pop, String continent, int highestpop) {

        if (pop > highestpop) {
            this.biggestContinent = continent; 
            highestpop = pop;
        }
        return highestpop;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably use a HashMap to solve your problem.

- Create a HashMap
- Iterate through your countryPopulationList and put the  to the map
- Get the item from the map with maximum value.

  For e.g.:

  ```
  String countryWithMaxPopulation = Collections.max(countryPopulationMap.entrySet(), (entry1, entry2) -> entry1.getValue() - entry2.getValue()).getKey();
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If you use java 8 streams, then it's really easy, without any boilerplate code:

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class LoopThroughVariablesToDetermineWhichIsTheLargest {

    public String findMostPopulousContinent() {
        //First read countries from disk into a bean. It's easy and better practise to manipulate the data in this way
        final List<Country> countries = this.readCountriesFromDisk();
        //Then we group population by continet
        final Map<String, Integer> continentPopulation = countries.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Country::getContinent, Collectors.summingInt(Country::getPopulation)));
        //And finally we return the asked result
        return Collections
                .max(continentPopulation.entrySet(), (entry1, entry2) -> entry1.getValue() - entry2.getValue())
                .getKey();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldGetMostPopulousContinentName() throws Exception {
        Assert.assertEquals("Asia", this.findMostPopulousContinent());
    }

    class Country {
        private final String name;
        private final String continent;
        private final int population;

        public Country(String name, String continent, int population) {
            super();
            this.name = name;
            this.continent = continent;
            this.population = population;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }

        public String getContinent() {
            return this.continent;
        }

        public int getPopulation() {
            return this.population;
        }
    }

    List<Country> readCountriesFromDisk() {
        // TODO read from disk

        // Provide example countries directly for simplicity
        return Arrays.asList(new Country("Spain", "Europe", 45), new Country("USA", "North America", 325),
                new Country("USA", "North America", 325), new Country("China", "Asia", 1380),
                new Country("Brasil", "South America", 207), new Country("India", "Asia", 1331),
                new Country("Nigeria", "Africa", 191), new Country("Indonesia", "Asia", 260),
                new Country("Turkey", "Europe", 79), new Country("Iran", "Asia", 80),
                new Country("Germany", "Europe", 82), new Country("Egypt", "Africa", 92),
                new Country("Vietnam", "Asia", 93), new Country("USA", "North America", 325));
    }
}
```